# How to use regular expression with arguments in TC Shell

Tags: regex, shell

I'm trying to write a simple shell script called `find_dict` which will find the given arguments in a certain dictionary.
The dictionary file is called `dictionary`. This is what I've tried:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach word ($argv)
    grep ^$word$ dictionary
end
```

That didn't work for me. However, by removing the second '$' sign it did worked but obviously it matched not only the given argument but also everything starting with it.
For example:

```
> find_dict ball
ball
balls
ballad
ballet
...
```

I Also tried `^[$word]$` `^($word)$` but neither have worked. 
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me. The quotes are interpreted by the shell before `grep` is executed:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach word ($argv)
    grep ^"${word}"$ dictionary
end
```